# Why did Heather go away?

Tags: doctor-who

In the first episode of the 10th season of Doctor Who, Heather took Bill to the puddle and

> wanted her to find out what is strange about it.

When Bill tried to do so, Heather went away.

Why did she do that?

> She obviously liked her, as we find out later.
>  And although she was strange, she was a regular human (maybe I could have another question, why she behaved so strangely).

Comment: We don't get a lot of insight into Heather.  The only things we can work with are (1) her and Bill's chemistry (2) she hates her unique eye (3) she wanted to be anywhere else and was nonspecific or whys or hows.  Unless she shows up again, pretty much anything is speculative.

Comment: Do you mean the moment when she merely walked away, or the time when she "disappeared"- because she was taken by the puddle?

Comment: The first one. I understand that in the second case she was taken by the puddle.

Comment: Maybe she thought she was mistaken that the puddle did something weird and didn't want to be laughed at for thinking a puddle was copying her. Hence coming back later to check.

Comment: @Bellerophon First idea which makes sense to me. But still, I think it is not true because she left in the moment when Bill was amazed by the strangeness of the puddle, so clearly, she wouldn't be laughed.

Comment: Late for a university class?

Comment: @Bellerophon Who cares about that ;).

Comment: Speculation only, but perhaps she felt that the puddle wanted to take her, and she tried to offer up Bill instead.

Answer (score 2):

I recall (having seen S10E01 only once) a display internal to the "puddle" or some other notification of "Pilot found" even before Heather had been take into the puddle.  The puddle/ship may have had enough control over Heather by that point to enlist her to assist as it was then seen to be "Searching for passenger".

Answer (score 0):

I think she was afraid of the puddle, and after alerting a random someone - which just so happened to be Bill - she took the chance to get away from it.

Comment: It was pretty clear Heather had seen it before, and obviously, she also came back afterwards.  Afraid? Sure.  Not enough to stay away though, so this answer doesn't really hold up.